# Выборка значений столбца массива в массив

Tags: php, pdo, modx

Упёрся в задачу такого плана...

Получаю я, значит, два массива из таблиц БД. Один с ФИО и датами рождений человеков, а другой со статьями написанными людьми со связью на человека из первой таблицы.

```
$arr_workr = $modx->getCollection('AaaWorkers',$where_workr);
$arr_rev = $modx->getCollection('AaaArticlesOfWorkers',$where_rev);
```

Так вот мне нужно как-то запросом передать в массив №2 условие массива №1, чтобы получить третий массив, в котором будут имена, фамилии, даты рождений писателей, названия статей, даты публикаций.

Сделал конструкцию цикл в цикле, работает. Но потом одумался, если будет много строк, то запросы будут очень долгими.

Пробовал при помощи

```
$arr_res = array_column($arr_workr, 'id');
print_r($arr_res );
```

выудить в массив id людей, чтоб потом передать его в параметр запроса на таблицу статей, но мне выводит:
`Array ()`

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

Comment: Сделайте print_r($arr_workr). Дальше Вам, скорее всего, не понадобится ничья помощь :-)

Comment: Точно. Появился результат. Спасибо большое, добрый человек))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Воспользовался методом print_r($arr_workr) по совету Александра